Does It Make Sense to Use Random Forest When Predictor Values Are Averaged by Groups?
In a nutshell: does it make sense to use Random Forest for analyzing the importance of predictors when predictor variables are averaged by groups of samples?
I'm working on an ecological data analysis project involving the diversity of soil bacteria richness across several islands (150 observations, 5 islands). However, due to constraints in our sampling method, our predictor variables (e.g., pH) are averaged across samples for each island, meaning I have for example one pH value per island and 50 values of bacterial richness (number of observations is not balanced per island).
I'm looking to use Random Forest (RF) to determine the key predictors affecting bacteria diversity across islands, but I'm unsure if averaging predictor variables per island affects the model's validity or interpretability. Can RF still be effective here, and are there any adjustments needed for the averaged predictors?
Note: Another option would be to average the bacterial richness and perform linear regression, but since Random Forest can capture non-linear relationships and interactions more "naturally" (and not assuming linear models restrictions), I would like to give this approach a chance.

Random forest is related to k-nearest neighbor, so I would try some other classifier first.

There's a few problems here and I would not recommend random forests for this.
Effectively, you have many technical replicates of diversity measurements at 5 locations. This is certainly better than having just one diversity measurement per island, but not by a huge amount. It is far less powerful than having separate predictor measurements for each diversity measurement.
Because you have just one predictor measurement per island, those predictor values are confounded with unmeasured differences between islands. Basically, you can't account well for any unmeasured differences. You could perhaps try fitting a hierarchical Bayesian model, but you'll probably need to use strong priors because of this confounding problem.
Random forests are powerful and good at picking up nonlinearities, but your dataset is small and you're extremely unlikely to learn much about these nonlinearities with just 5 levels per predictor even if all your points were truly independent. And they are not - you'd still have to account for the nonindependence. This is possible through mixed-effects random forests (see How can I include random effects (or repeated measures) into a randomForest), but is very unlikely to work in this situation because of the data limitations. Another option is a GAMM, but you'd run into similar problems.
So I'd recommend doing an exploratory analysis instead. Visualise how your diversity values change as a function of your predictors. This can easily be done in one dimension, and using colour can be done with two. With >2 it becomes challenging, but I don't think your data would allow you to meaningfully explore high-dimensional interactions anyway.
